# JPA/Metamodel: Strange (inconsistent ?) example in Sun Docs

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api, metamodel

In [Sun Online resources](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/821-1841/gjiup?l=en&a=view), they provide son example about the usage of the Criteria/Metamodel API, but as far as I understand Java, it seems to be impossible to work:

```
CriteriaQuery<Pet> cq = cb.createQuery(Pet.class);
Metamodel m = em.getMetamodel();
EntityType<Pet> Pet_ = m.entity(Pet.class);
EntityType<Owner> Owner_ = m.entity(Owner.class);

Root<Pet> pet = cq.from(Pet.class);
Join<Owner, Address> address = cq.join(**Pet_.owners**).join(**Owner_.addresses**);
```

`Pet_` is a *instance* of class  [`EntityType`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/metamodel/EntityType.html) which **doesn't** define any attribute named `owners` or `addresses`.

They do define classes named `Pet_` and `Owner_` for the metamodel, but they importation here would create a conflict with the variable names ... Am I right?

__

(the question is also related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854687/jpa-hibernate-static-metamodel-attributes-not-populated-nullpointerexception))

Comment: There's no `CriteriaQuery.join` as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This example is **incorrect**, the authors are mixing *canonical static metamodel classes* (generated) with classes obtained via the Metamodel API. They are supposed to use either the weakly typed API or the stronlgy typed generated classes, not both together. In their case, the `Pet_` (which is an incredible bad naming choice and is misleading) indeed doesn't have any `owners` attribute. 
This should be reported, this part of the tutorial is misleading and wrong.

#### See also

- [Dynamic, typesafe queries in JPA 2.0](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/#N102F5)