# NullPointerException at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.get

Tags: java, jpa, nullpointerexception, predicate, criteria-api

This works fine:

```
 public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Campaign> root,
    CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    return root.get("campState").get("statusId").in(campStatus);
}
```

but I change to ：

```
 return  root.get(Campaign_.campState).get(CampState_.campId).in(campStatus).
```

And it throws exception：

> edit for: NullPointerException at   org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.get

```
  @StaticMetamodel(Campaign.class)
  public class Campaign_ {
  public static volatile SingularAttribute<Campaign, CampState> campState;
  public static volatile SingularAttribute<Campaign, Long> campId;
  }

  @StaticMetamodel(CampState.class)
  public class CampState_ {
  public static volatile SingularAttribute<CampState, String> statusId;
  }

  Campaign.class
  @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE})
  @JoinColumn(name = "camp_status")
  public CampState getCampState() {
    return campState;
  }

  public void setCampState(CampState campState) {
    this.campState = campState;
  }
```

Comment: Add please whole stack trace of the error.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.yunat.ccms.biz.core.specification.CampaignSpecifications$1.toPredicate(CampaignSpecifications.java:24)
 at

Comment: 24 line is     return root.get("campState").get("statusId").in(campStatus);

Answer (score 2):

check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4892085/1211174).

seems like metamodel and class should be at the same package

Comment: The "package solution" was just an assumption and has no explanation why nor how it fixes the issue.

Comment: the `meta model`  and the `class` should be at the same package....this is a requirement

Answer (score 0):

Given two queries operate to different attributes. Second query cannot be compiled, because CampState_ does not have attribute campId (Campaign_ does have such a attribute.

Query that is equivalent to first one with static metamodel is:

```
root.get(Campaign_.campState).get(CampState_.statusId).in(campStatus).
```