# It needs to create Predicate with date in Criteria API, but still gets an exception. How to build such Predicate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, criteria-api

```
    private CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder;
    private CriteriaQuery<Points> criteriaQuery;
    private Root<Points> root;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Points.class);
        root = criteriaQuery.from(entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(Points.class));
    }
    public void t(Date lowerLimit, Date upperLimit) {
      Predicate startPredicate = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.<Date>get(Points_.createdOn), lowerLimit);
    }
```

Exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:123)

I use hibernate 5.2.10.Final version.

Root is not null:
[image]

Metamodel and entity are in the same package:
[image]

Points_ class:

```
package ...domain.points.model;
@StaticMetamodel(Points.class)
public class Points_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Points, Date> createdOn;
    ....
}
```

Points class:

```
package ...domain.points.model;
@Entity
@Table(name = "POINTS")
public class Points extends AuditingEntity {
...
}
```

AuditingEntity class:

```
@Audited
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class AuditingEntity implements Serializable {
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "CREATED_ON")
    protected Date createdOn;
    ......
}
```

Comment: Check again. Try to use Point.fieldName instead of metamodel. Add your stacktrace to the question and tell which version of hibernate you use. Please.

Comment: fieldName are the same, but @Entity Points extend other table, which have field createdOn, and I use hibernate 5.2.10.Final version.

Comment: You mean if your class Point does not extend anything, you can use metamodel? I always used Strings, see my updated answer with example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20097800/4587961

Is metamodel and entity in the same package? `Points_` and `Points`
You say **yes**.

Now, let's try to replace metamodel with String field name.

```
 Predicate startPredicate = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.<Date>get("createdOn"), lowerLimit);
```

I just want to see if it works, and then continue to search a solution.

Check this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4256642/4587961

---

I am afraid there is a bug in Hibernate
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9259

I used hardcoded Strings. I would create a class `PointTable` with all fields from `Point`. These classes can be in different packages.

Point

```
package entities;

public class Point {

    private Long id;
    //Other fields.

    @ID
    @Column(PointTable.ID)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    //Other getters and setters.
}
```

PointTable

```
package entities.table;

public class PointTable {

    public static final String ID = "id";
    public static final String CREATED_ON = "createdOn";
    //Other fields.
}
```