# Allow empty set in three table join in Spring Data JPA Specification

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am joining three tables in a Spring Data JPA `Specification`, as such:

```
public static Specification<Contact> findByStructureCode(final String code) {
    return new Specification<Contact>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Contact> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
            return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.join(Contact_.contactToStructures)
                    .join(ContactToStructure_.structureCodes)
                    .get(StructureCode_.code), code);
        }
    };
}
```

However, this is giving me a good old `NullPointerException`.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.AbstractFromImpl.constructJoin(AbstractFromImpl.java:345) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.AbstractFromImpl.join(AbstractFromImpl.java:333) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.AbstractFromImpl.join(AbstractFromImpl.java:324) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at my.package.ContactSpecification$3.toPredicate(ContactSpecification.java:83) ~[MyProject-1.0.0.jar:na]
```

Note that I have replaced package and jar information in that last line with fake information. The line in my code that the stack trace references is `.join(ContactToStructure_.structureCodes)`.

I believe this is being caused by the fact that not all `Contact` rows have corresponding `ContactToStructure` rows in my database.

So, how can I do the first join to allow for `Contact` entities with an empty `contactToStructures` set, and just return contacts with non-empty `contactToStructures` sets?

---

Here are the relevant pieces of the entities and their metamodels.

**Contact.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTACT", schema = "myschema")
public class Contact {    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<ContactToStructure> contactToStructures = new HashSet<>(0);    
}
```

**Contact_.java**

```
@StaticMetamodel(Contact.class)
public class Contact_ {
    public static volatile SetAttribute<Contact, ContactToStructure> contactToStructures;
}
```

**ContactToStructure.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTACT_TO_STRUCTURE", schema = "myschema")
public class ContactToStructure {
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="contactToStructure")
    private Collection<StructureCode> structureCodes = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**ContactToStructure_.java**

```
@StaticMetamodel(ContactToStructure.class)
public class ContactToStructure_ {
    public static volatile SetAttribute<ContactToStructure, StructureCode> structureCodes;
}
```

**StructureCode.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STRUCTURE_CODE", schema = "myschema")
public class StructureCode {
    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;
}
```

**StructureCode_.java**

```
@StaticMetamodel(StructureCode.class)
public class StructureCode_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<StructureCode, String> code;
}
```

Comment: It's not what you fear (in fact, the query you are building should yield the behavior you desire).  The exception is being thrown long before any query is sent to the database.  My belief is that you are running into this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854687/jpa-hibernate-static-metamodel-attributes-not-populated-nullpointerexception

Comment: Nope, my metamodels are all in the same package as their corresponding entity, and are named exactly the same, other than the metamodel class name and file name containing an underscore at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If still relevant 
try to make the following change `ContactToStructure_.java`:

```
public static volatile SetAttribute<Version, UseCase> useCases;
```

To:

```
public static volatile CollectionAttribute<Version, UseCase> useCases;
```