# Hibernate/JPA - NullPointerException when accessing SingularAttribute parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, metamodel

I'm trying to use JPA2 type-safe criteria queries with Hibernate 5.0.7.Final.

```
...
criteria.where( builder.equal( root.get(SingularAttribute.attr), value ));
//where parameters are
//criteria.where( builder.equal( root.get(Person_.name), "Can" ));
...
```

The root.get always throw `NullPointerException`.
The metamodel class `Person_` for `Person` is generated by `org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor`.

A similar problem was asked in [JPA/Hibernate Static Metamodel Attributes not Populated -- NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854687/jpa-hibernate-static-metamodel-attributes-not-populated-nullpointerexception?newreg=3763443bb63f40c2a94bc599da533425) but this time both classes are in the same package.

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:123)
```

My code:

Interface that i use to make sure they will have `getId();`.

```
package it.unibz.db.hibernate.model;

public interface ModelInterface<PK extends Serializable> extends Serializable {
    PK getId();
}
```

Model class

```
package it.unibz.db.hibernate.model;

@Entity
@Table(name ="person")
public class Person implements ModelInterface<Integer> {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    //other getter and setters
}
```

Generated metamodel Person_ class

```
package it.unibz.db.hibernate.model;

@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(Person.class)
public abstract class Person_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Person, String> name;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Person, Integer> id;

}
```

Generic DAO class that i inherit with PersonDao

```
public class GenericDao<E extends ModelInterface<PK>, PK extends Serializable> implements DaoInterface<E, PK> {
private Class<E> type;

public GenericDao(Class<E> type) {
    this.type = type;
    //called as super(ClassName.class); eg. super(Person.class);
}

public List<E> readBy(SingularAttribute column, String value) throws Exception {
    EntityManager em = HibernateUtil.getEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<E> criteria = builder.createQuery(type);
    Root<E> root = criteria.from(type);

    criteria.select(root);
    criteria.where( builder.equal( root.get(column), value ));
    List<E> entityList = em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
    em.close();
    return entityList;
    }
}
```

Some of my dependencies

- hibernate-c3p0          5.0.7.Final
- hibernate-entitymanager 5.0.7.Final
- postgresql              9.4.1207.jre7
- hibernate-jpamodelgen   5.0.7.Final

**EDIT:**

Running this code in the main method works

```
EntityManager em = HibernateUtil.getEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> criteria = builder.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> root = criteria.from(Person.class);
criteria.select(root);
criteria.where( builder.equal( root.get(Person_.name), "Can" ));
List<Person> entityList = em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
//do stuff with entityList
```

but the same code covered in a method throws `NullPointerException`.

```
public List<Person> readBy(SingularAttribute column, String value) throws Exception {
    log.debug("Reading entity by");

    EntityManager em = HibernateUtil.getEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Person> criteria = builder.createQuery(Person.class);
    Root<Person> root = criteria.from(Person.class);

    criteria.select(root);
    criteria.where( builder.equal( root.get(column), value ));
    List<Person> entityList = em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
    em.close();
    return entityList;
}
```

So it seems that the problem is passing `SingularAttribute` parameter to the method `readBy(SingularAttribute column, String value)`.

I tested this code in main and this prints `false`

```
EntityManager em = HibernateUtil.getEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> criteria = builder.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> root = criteria.from(Person.class);
System.out.println(root.get(Person_.name) == null); //false
```

meanwhile this throws `InvocationTargetException` caused by `NullPointerException` at `root.get(column)`.

```
//invoked as personDao.test(Person_.name) from main
public void test(SingularAttribute column) {
    EntityManager em = HibernateUtil.getEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Person> criteria = builder.createQuery(Person.class);
    Root<Person> root = criteria.from(Person.class);
    System.out.println(root.get(column) == null); //InvocationTargetException
}
```

Is this what it's supposed to do? How can i pass `SingularAttribute` object to a method as a parameter?

Comment: Thanks man, adding `public void init(){} //does nothing` in my HibernateSessionFactory class and calling it from outside solved the problem for me as well. Very strange indeed. Does anyone know why, how and why?

Comment: You can answer your own question instead of editing it with the answer - which is more recommended.

Comment: Thanks @Samoth. I accepted the solution as an answer, though the reason behind it is still missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `HibernateUtil.getEntityManager()` in main before method call somehow works. **It even works when i call literally a empty block of a method `init()`.** 
It could be related with initialization of classes. Here's the code snippet.

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static EntityManagerFactory emFactory;
    private static EntityManager em;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateUtil.class);
    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT = "pt";
    static{
        log.info("Creating entity manager factory");
        emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
    }
    //calling this from main before PersonDao's method calls somehow works...
    public void init(){} //does nothing
    public static EntityManager getEntityManager(){
        if(em != null && em.isOpen()){
            closeEntityManager();
        }
        log.debug("Creating new entity manager");
        em = emFactory.createEntityManager();
        return em;
    }
    public static void close() throws Exception {
        if(em != null && em.isOpen()){
            closeEntityManager();
        }
        log.info("Closing entity manager factory");
        emFactory.close();
    }
    private static void closeEntityManager(){
        log.info("Closing last entity manager");
        em.close();
    }
}
```