# How to inject hibernate metamodel in spring test context without full hibernate connection?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, metamodel

I have entity.

```
@Entity
class Foo {
    @Column
    Long id;
    /* ... */
}
```

Hibernate generates Metamodel for it:

```
@StaticMetamodel(Foo.class)
public abstract class Foo_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Foo, Long> id;
    /* ... */
}
```

I want to do some tests *without database connection*. But I need to get value of `Foo_.id.getName()` for use in reflection.

Unfortunately it doesn't work in test context. This **test failed**:

```
@Test
public void metaModelTest() {
    Assert.assertTrue(Foo_.id != null);
}
```

I found here: [JPA/Hibernate Static Metamodel Attributes not Populated -- NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854687/jpa-hibernate-static-metamodel-attributes-not-populated-nullpointerexception)

> When the Hibernate EntityManagerFactory is being built, it will look for a canonical metamodel class for each of the managed typed is knows about and if it finds any it will inject the appropriate metamodel information into them, as outlined in [JPA 2 Specification, section 6.2.2, pg 200]

Is there way to get mock EntityManagerFactory that will do it? Perhaps there are other solutions?

**Note:** tests are in Spring test context.

Answer (score 2):

My current solition is this:

```
@Component
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked", "serial" })
public class MockMetaModelGenerator {
    private static final String BASE_PACKAGE = "com.example.foo";

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
        scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Entity.class));
        for (BeanDefinition bd : scanner.findCandidateComponents(BASE_PACKAGE)) {
            Class<?> metamodel;
            try {
                metamodel = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass(bd.getBeanClassName() + "_");
                for (Field field : metamodel.getFields()) {
                    field.set(null, new GenericAttrImpl(field.getName()));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Throwables.propagate(e);
            }
        }
    }

    static class GenericAttrImpl extends AbstractAttribute implements CollectionAttribute, SetAttribute, ListAttribute, MapAttribute,
            SingularAttribute {
        GenericAttrImpl(String name) {
            super(name, null, null, null, null);
        }
        /* Mock realization of other methods */
    }
}
```

Full code on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/Ncc8Ty46

Ugly but works.